# Faster joining on 'most recent' related rows

Tags: postgresql, performance, optimization, query-performance

I have a bug tracking application. The `bug` table stores very little,
because every state change to a bug happens by adding a comment. For
example, the current state of a bug is determined by the `state` value
of the most recent comment that changed state (`comment.state IS NOT
NULL`). This requires some nasty queries that find the comment with the
highest id that changed the property in question.

This is what the schema looks like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE bug (
    id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    title character varying
);


CREATE TABLE comment (
    id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    state character varying,
    created_at timestamp without time zone,
    priority character varying,
    creator_id integer,
    bug_id integer references bug(id)
);
```

Here is the query for the index page, that shows open bugs ordered by most recently modified. Can it be made any faster?

```sql
SELECT bug.id AS id,
       bug.title AS title,
       comment_1.state AS state,
       comment_2.created_at AS created_at,
       comment_2.creator_id AS creator_id,
       comment_3.priority AS priority,
       comment_4.created_at AS last_modified,
       comment_4.creator_id AS last_modified_by 
FROM bug
JOIN
  (SELECT bug_id,
          MAX(id) AS id
   FROM comment
   WHERE state IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY bug_id) AS max_state ON max_state.bug_id = bug.id
JOIN comment comment_1 ON comment_1.id = max_state.id    -- comment that changed the state
JOIN
  (SELECT bug_id,
          MIN(id) AS id
   FROM comment
   GROUP BY bug_id) AS min_created ON min_created.bug_id = bug.id
JOIN comment comment_2 ON comment_2.id = min_created.id  -- first comment
JOIN
  (SELECT bug_id,
          MAX(id) AS id
   FROM comment
   WHERE priority IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY bug_id) AS max_priority ON max_priority.bug_id = bug.id
JOIN comment comment_3 ON comment_3.id = max_priority.id  -- comment that changed priority
JOIN
  (SELECT bug_id,
          MAX(id) AS id
   FROM comment
   GROUP BY bug_id) AS max_modified ON max_modified.bug_id = bug.id
JOIN comment comment_4 ON comment_4.id = max_modified.id  -- most recent comment
WHERE comment_1.state != 'closed'
ORDER BY last_modified;
```

The query plan:

```
Sort  (cost=195712503.78..196700370.73 rows=395146780 width=90) (actual time=356.245..356.278 rows=292 loops=1)
  Sort Key: comment_4.created_at
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 72kB
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=15013.56..17735920.72 rows=395146780 width=90) (actual time=333.743..356.022 rows=292 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: ((max(public.comment.id)) = comment_4.id)
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=12793.54..13526.05 rows=395146780 width=86) (actual time=301.028..316.924 rows=292 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (public.comment.bug_id = bug.id)
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=3552.21..4237.15 rows=8287 width=12) (actual time=54.202..68.236 rows=292 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: ((max(public.comment.id)) = comment_1.id)
                    ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1384.50..1487.00 rows=10250 width=8) (actual time=28.765..32.867 rows=12418 loops=1)
                          ->  Seq Scan on comment  (cost=0.00..1118.34 rows=53232 width=8) (actual time=0.004..9.692 rows=53320 loops=1)
                                Filter: (state IS NOT NULL)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=1276.68..1276.68 rows=51203 width=12) (actual time=25.288..25.288 rows=41028 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 4096  Batches: 4  Memory Usage: 485kB
                          ->  Seq Scan on comment comment_1  (cost=0.00..1276.68 rows=51203 width=12) (actual time=0.008..13.326 rows=41028 loops=1)
                                Filter: ((state)::text <> 'closed'::text)
              ->  Hash  (cost=9210.42..9210.42 rows=2473 width=90) (actual time=246.798..246.798 rows=12418 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 2 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 1025kB
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=5626.70..9210.42 rows=2473 width=90) (actual time=170.565..237.003 rows=12418 loops=1)
                          ->  Merge Join  (cost=5626.70..7964.40 rows=2473 width=86) (actual time=170.537..207.449 rows=12418 loops=1)
                                Merge Cond: (comment_3.id = (max(public.comment.id)))
                                ->  Index Scan using comment_pkey on comment comment_3  (cost=0.00..2142.27 rows=63334 width=10) (actual time=0.014..14.553 rows=63327 loops=1)
                                ->  Sort  (cost=5626.70..5632.88 rows=2473 width=84) (actual time=170.514..175.504 rows=12418 loops=1)
                                      Sort Key: (max(public.comment.id))
                                      Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 1216kB
                                      ->  Hash Join  (cost=5172.96..5487.32 rows=2473 width=84) (actual time=129.948..146.909 rows=12418 loops=1)
                                            Hash Cond: (public.comment.bug_id = bug.id)
                                            ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1435.01..1556.96 rows=12195 width=8) (actual time=30.173..34.362 rows=12420 loops=1)
                                                  ->  Seq Scan on comment  (cost=0.00..1118.34 rows=63334 width=8) (actual time=0.002..6.794 rows=63334 loops=1)
                                            ->  Hash  (cost=3706.46..3706.46 rows=2519 width=76) (actual time=99.742..99.742 rows=12418 loops=1)
                                                  Buckets: 1024  Batches: 2 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 1025kB
                                                  ->  Hash Join  (cost=3391.64..3706.46 rows=2519 width=76) (actual time=74.910..92.291 rows=12418 loops=1)
                                                        Hash Cond: (public.comment.bug_id = bug.id)
                                                        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1435.01..1556.96 rows=12195 width=8) (actual time=30.358..34.751 rows=12420 loops=1)
                                                              ->  Seq Scan on comment  (cost=0.00..1118.34 rows=63334 width=8) (actual time=0.003..7.033 rows=63334 loops=1)
                                                        ->  Hash  (cost=1924.57..1924.57 rows=2565 width=68) (actual time=44.522..44.522 rows=12418 loops=1)
                                                              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 2 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 1025kB
                                                              ->  Merge Join  (cost=1381.46..1924.57 rows=2565 width=68) (actual time=23.613..36.985 rows=12418 loops=1)
                                                                    Merge Cond: (bug.id = public.comment.bug_id)
                                                                    ->  Index Scan using bug_pkey on bug  (cost=0.00..473.58 rows=12420 width=60) (actual time=0.014..4.511 rows=12420 loops=1)
                                                                    ->  Sort  (cost=1381.46..1387.88 rows=2565 width=8) (actual time=23.592..25.776 rows=12418 loops=1)
                                                                          Sort Key: public.comment.bug_id
                                                                          Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 967kB
                                                                          ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1184.93..1210.58 rows=2565 width=8) (actual time=13.333..17.261 rows=12418 loops=1)
                                                                                ->  Seq Scan on comment  (cost=0.00..1118.34 rows=13317 width=8) (actual time=0.003..6.372 rows=13325 loops=1)
                                                                                      Filter: (priority IS NOT NULL)
                          ->  Index Scan using comment_pkey on comment comment_2  (cost=0.00..0.49 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=12418)
                                Index Cond: (id = (min(public.comment.id)))
        ->  Hash  (cost=1118.34..1118.34 rows=63334 width=12) (actual time=32.547..32.547 rows=63334 loops=1)
              Buckets: 4096  Batches: 4  Memory Usage: 686kB
              ->  Seq Scan on comment comment_4  (cost=0.00..1118.34 rows=63334 width=12) (actual time=0.012..14.321 rows=63334 loops=1)
Total runtime: 357.332 ms
```

Comment: Relying on ordering by ID is not a very good practice, I think.  In a few similar cases I keep a `current boolean` column, with new entries always being TRUE, the last current entry set to FALSE at insertion of the new entry.

Comment: I know it's not usually good practice, but they do provide a total order. I originally used the created_at timestamp to do the ordering, but ran into issues with collisions (two comments in the same second).

A `current` field wouldn't work well in this case, because for each property (`state`, `priority`, etc), a different row is 'current'.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest re-thinking your design a little bit.

You may want to have an active bool attribute to the comments, and a set of unique indexes to ensure that only the most recent comment of a certain type can be active.  Then you can join using the flag instead of max and subqueries.  Not only that but you get the benefit of a unique index across only the records you are interested in.  I would also suggest a bug class id so that you can categorize the bugs that way for join conditions.

In that case your index definition would be something like:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX bug_comment_class_id_idx_u ON comment(bug_class_id, bug_id) where active;
```

You can then:

```
CREATE INDEX comment_bug_id_idx ON comment(bug_id) where active;
```

And replace your multiple joins with a single join and a case statement.